# Read input file from jar while running application from spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, executable-jar, spark-submit

I have an input file that is custom delimited and is passed to newAPIHadoopFile to convert as RDD[String]. The file resides under the project resource directory. The following code works well when run from the Eclipse IDE.

```
  val path = this.getClass()
                 .getClassLoader()
                 .getResource(fileName)                   
                 .toURI().toString()
  val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration() 
  conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", recordDelimiter)

  return sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
      path,
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable], 
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text], 
      conf)
    .map(_._2.toString)
```

However when I run it on spark-submit (with a uber jar) as follows

```
   spark-submit /Users/anon/Documents/myUber.jar
```

I get the below error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: jar:file:/Users/anon/Documents/myUber.jar!/myhome-data.json
```

Any inputs please?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is for `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` that requires a path not an input stream, I'd recommend using `--files` option of `spark-submit`.

> **--files FILES** Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor. File paths of these files in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).

See [SparkFiles.get](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$) method:

> Get the absolute path of a file added through `SparkContext.addFile()`.

With that, you should use `spark-submit` as follows:

```
spark-submit --files fileNameHere /Users/anon/Documents/myUber.jar
```

---

In a general case, if a file is inside a jar file, you should use `InputStream` to access the file (not as a `File` directly).

The code could look as follows:

```
val content = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(
  classOf[yourObject].getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(yourFileNameHere)
```

See Scala's [Source](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.11/#scala.io.Source$) object and Java's [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) method.

Comment: I've tried this but the sc.newAPIHadoopFile requires a path and not input stream